# Session variables are not being preserved when set from one directory deep

Tags: php, session

This is a weird issue. I have a folder structure like this. I simplified it for this question.

**Folder Structure**

[image]

The Session variable `id` is being set by a file named `index.php` inside the folder `deep` Then, when I come back to the root folder and open `index.php` The session variable doesn't show up. (It's value is not being set)

**Code in the file: deep/index.php:**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo session_id();
    $_SESSION['id'] = "bro";
    print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

**Code in the file: /index.php:**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo session_id();

    print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

This example works on my localhost. (The `/index` file displays an array with the Session variable..) But on my live server it doesn't work. The `/index` says `Array()` while it should display the set data. Although, the **session_id() matches**. It is actually a subdomain (something.somewhere.com) and doesn't really start with a "www".

Comment: probaly the session cookie is path-restricted. check your browser and see if the cookies are set for `/` and `/deep`

Comment: @MarcB good thinking but if PHP kept the sessions separate, wouldn't the session ids be mismatched?  The OP says they're the same.

Comment: OP If you set a session variable in `/index.php`, then try to run the same file later to retrieve the variable, can you see it?

Comment: no idea if op's talking about session_id, or the $_SESSION['id']

Comment: @MarcB it's `session_id` right? because OP says session variable shows up as an empty array

Comment: Its the session_id() that matches, guys. And yes, I can see the variable if it was set on the same page. The variable can also been seen if viewed from another file in the same directory.

Comment: [Live Example](http://things.haidrr.com/check/) The directory structure is the same. "check" is the root where all of these files are.  And unset.php destroys session if you wanna check things @MarcB

Comment: If the path on the cookie is set to the cwd, then there will certainly be weird things happening (it will change according to which page you visit first). It would be a lot simpler to look at te HTTP traffic and see what cookies are being passed about than trying to diagnose an obscure set of symptoms.

Comment: @symcbean could it be hosting setting issue?

Comment: ...or a lot of other things. LOOK AT THE HTTP TRAFFIC